# Como puedo acceder a los datos que retorna la respuesta de HttpRequest de akka scala?

Tags: scala

Estoy haciendo una petición tipo GET de la siguiente manera a una API externa:

```
val headers = List(RawHeader("Api-Key", "myapikey"), RawHeader("Api-Username", "user"))

val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(
   HttpRequest(
      method = HttpMethods.GET,
      uri = "http://externalurl.com/users/by-external/2.json",
      entity = HttpEntity(
         ContentTypes.`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, s"&language=Scala&theme=Sunburst"
      )
   ).withHeaders(headers)
)
responseFuture.onComplete {
   case Success(response) =>
      response.discardEntityBytes()
      println(s"The request was successful and returned: $response")
   case Failure(ex) =>
      println(s"The request failed with: $ex")
}
```

Actualmente la respuesta que arroja es "The request was successful and returned: HttpResponse(413 Payload Too Large,List)". Como puedo acceder a los datos que retorna el array?. En este caso el array esperado es el siguiente:

```
{
   user_badges: [id:1],
   user: [name: "test"],
}
```

Comment: Y al descargar ese JSON, qué tamaño tiene?

Comment: @Alfabravo en postman me arroja un tamaño de 13.74KB

Answer (score 0):

Un [HttpResponse](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.2.6/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpResponse.html) de Akka tiene un campo llamado `entity` que es de tipo [ResponseEntity](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.2.6/akka/http/scaladsl/model/ResponseEntity.html) y eso tiene un campo `dataBytes` que te regresa un `Source[ByteString, Any]` de donde puedes leer el contenido de la respuesta como parte de un Akka Stream. (En tu caso: `response.entity.dataBytes` de tipo `Source[ByteString, Any]`)

Una segunda opcion es pasar el `entity` (no el `Source`) por un Unmarhaller; esto es especialmente util si ya no lo vas a pasar por Akka Streams. (En tu caso: `Unmarshal(entity).to[String]` de tipo `String`)

Sin embargo, cabe mencionar que tu codigo esta mandando contenido en el cuerpo de la petición y eso no es compatible con un `GET` (por eso obtienes un error HTTP 413)